# WinUI3 MONZA::DdiThreadingContext Exception while drag and drop

Tags: winui-3, c++-winrt, windows-kernel, windows-app-sdk

I'm getting the below exception when dropping a dragged item (any item) and the Drop callback doesn't work. I tried declaring the callback in other components, but to the same result.

```
C++/WinRT version: 2.0.230706.1
WindowsAppSDK Version: 1.4.230913002
```

The error:

```
Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::DdiThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x0000001AFB4FFDF0.
```

This is how I declare the callback:

```
<Border x:Name="BorderName"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColor}"
        BorderThickness="1"
        Padding="16,8"
        AllowDrop="True"
        Drop="Image_OnDrop">
```

Any idea what could be the problem? The exception doesn't crash the app, but the drop callback is not called.

The stack trace:

```
>   KernelBase.dll!00007ffdc7454ffc()   Unknown
    igd10um64xe.dll!00007ffdb93e2830()  Unknown
    igd10um64xe.dll!00007ffdb98c1d9c()  Unknown
    igd10um64xe.dll!00007ffdb92c3aff()  Unknown
    igd10um64xe.dll!00007ffdb93b8b26()  Unknown
    igd10um64xe.dll!00007ffdb93f3d6a()  Unknown
    kernel32.dll!00007ffdc8c4257d() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!00007ffdc9caaa78()    Unknown
```

Comment: Is it a first chance exception that you see or does it crashes your app? Seems like an intel GPU driver (igd10umd64.dll) issue. Google for igd10umd64.dll.

Comment: The exception doesn't crash the app, but the drop callback is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add a `background` to the border.

And then you need to handle the `DragOver` event. You need to specify what kind of operations your app supports by using the `AcceptedOperation` property.

For more details you could refer to the Doc:[Handle the DragOver event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/drag-and-drop#handle-the-dragover-event)

And as far as I'm concerned, the exception can be ignored.